# MySQL AES_DECRYPT wrong/strange result

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

Under my development machine WAMP, AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT is not working as required, also i tested with ENCODE and DECODE and same happen... I'm not understading why...

```
SELECT 
AES_ENCRYPT('text', SHA1('My secret passphrase')) as enc, 
AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('text', SHA1('My secret passphrase')), SHA1('My secret passphrase')) as denc
```

Result:

enc : 3278167d9d630327c74d83067964c9b6
denc: 74657874

text after encryption doesn't look good and decryption is wrong too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is working even on your side but it is blob data you are seeing.

denc: 74 65 78 74

74=t 65=e 78=x 74=t, add them together you get 'text'

ascii table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

try it with `cast` to make it more obvious:

```
SELECT cast(AES_ENCRYPT('text', SHA1('My secret passphrase')) as char(100)) as enc, 
cast(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('text', SHA1('My secret passphrase')), SHA1('My secret passphrase')) as char(100)) as denc
```

Comment: it works, except for enc returned blank, denc return the correct 'text'. Also why it happens? I see some online examples and they dont need to cast for it work/show real values

Comment: enc is not blank it is just not pretty visual and on some gui's it is simply not shown. if you select into an enc variable then send that thru decrypt you are back to `text`. it is there. it is hex gibberish that will mean nothing to you

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. Other question i have, im looking for a good solution to store PrivateKeys in the database, what should i use to mantain that keys? I need a good and stable encryption. AES_ENCRYPT or ENCODE or other?

Comment: i would write that up as a separate question. give it some thought as you need to think about the requirements. details as much as possible. collect your thoughts on it and you will get some good answers. some of us are crypto guys. include the `cryptography` and `encryption` tags to the question